How to use lightning Dashboard in VF page?
I attempted to embed the dashboard within the VF page, but I’m getting a “refuse to connect” error. Below is the code I used:
<div id="dashboardContainer" style="display: none;">
    <apex:iframe src="/Dashboard/01ZdL000002ntdJUAQ/view" width="100%" height="600px" />
</div>

Issue: The dashboard fails to load and throws the connection error. I suspect it might be a permission issue or a restriction related to Salesforce settings.enter image description here
I've tried this code
<div id="dashboardContainer" style="display: none;">
    <apex:iframe src="/Dashboard/01ZdL000002ntdJUAQ/view" width="100%" height="600px" />
</div>

I'm expecting dashboard in VF Page.

Check the browser's console for errors like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63474776/313628 and then you could try experimenting with Setup -> Content Security Policy (CSP)?
